# WHY I am not able to get state from redux to my React app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, switch-statement

Here's my code. I want to fetch ingredients and totalPrice from redux state but when I fetch it in main app, it is giving my undefined (this.props.ingredients and this.props.totalPrice).

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    ingredients: {
        salad: 0,
        bacon: 0,
        cheese: 0,
        meat: 0,
    },
    totalPrice: 4.0
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_INGREDIENTS':
            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer
```

Main App (Connecting with app)

```
......
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ings: state.ingredients,
        tp: state.totalPrice
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Burgerbuilder, axios)
```

This is giving me undefined

```
console.log(this.props.ings) 
console.log(this.props.tp)
```

Here's how it connected it with store

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import reducer from './redux/reducer';


const store = createStore(reducer)

const app = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App /> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: Did you use combineReducers?

Comment: Can you can through my code that I haven't used combineReducer

Comment: Have you tried looking at your state in Reactotron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer must **always** return a complete state.  Inside `case "ADD_INGREDIENTS":` you `break` and don't return anything.  So calling an action with `{ type: "ADD_INGREDIENTS" }` will cause your whole state to be `undefined`.  You need to `return state`.

Additionally, I don't understand what your are trying to do by including `axios` in your `connect`.  It should be `connect(mapStateToProps)(Burgerbuilder)`.

Comment: Much Appreciated Linda. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `combineReducer` function.

In your reducers directory create a file called `index.js` for example, then add this code to it

```
import ingredientsReducer from './reducer'
export default combineReducers(
  {
    ingredients: ingredientsReducer,
  }
);
```

then in your main.js file, when you create a store, feed this exported combineReducers result to it.

---

You can read more about [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#:%7E:text=This%20function%20helps%20you%20organize,same%20logical%20division%20between%20reducers.) here

Comment: I am not solving this using combineReducer because there is no need. I am solving this using single reducer